# Javascript prototype constructor throws error when imported in Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I have an Angular application in which I am trying to import a JS file which has a constructor. But when I run the application, webpack throws error.

Javascript file in assets:

```
TestServiceClient = function(arg1, arg2) {

};
module.exports = TestServiceClient;
module.exports.default = TestServiceClient;
```

Importing in Angular:

```
var TestServiceClient = require('../assets/test');

@Injectable()
export class ServiceTest {
  constructor() {
    const svc = new TestServiceClient('testarg1', 'testarg2');
  }
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: TestServiceClient is not defined
    at 3472 (test.js:1:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
```

Could you please help me spot the issue here?

Comment: Is there some code that exports the function?

Comment: @Pointy It does not work even with exports.

Answer (score 0):

I had to export it this way:

```
exports.TestServiceClient = function(arg1, arg2) {

};
```